# Unable to find index for $geoNear query, code: 2, code-name: 'badValue'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geo, 2dsphere

This is my Schema

```
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    skills: [{
        type: String
    }],
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            index: '2dsphere'
        },

        coordinates: []
    }
});
```

And my query looks something like this

```
    User.find({
    location: {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [77.032448, 28.590654]
            },
            $maxDistance: 2000
        }
    }
   }).find((error, results) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(results);
   });
```

Whenever I run the code, I am getting this error

```
    ok: 0,
  errmsg:
   'error processing query: ns=StudyJamm.usersTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=2000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  code: 2,
  codeName: 'BadValue',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
```

PS:-  I already tried `User.index({location: "2dsphere"});`

What am I doing wrong here?
I have gone through all the similar questions on Stack Overflow, but no solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The location will be stored like below in mongoDB.

```
location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
}
```

So just check your definition of location again. `type` value is fixed to "point" here always, try to model that as static value. And the index you have specified should be on `location`  not inside `type`.

You can check from DB if there is a index created  by this query

```
db.getCollection('data').getIndexes()
```

If not then there is problem with index creation.  I got below code from https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index

```
var s = new Schema({ loc: { type: [Number], index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: true }})
```